# How to convert a JS array of of objects to a different formate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects and want to convert it from one formate to another formate to prepare it to plot on a d3 graph, I want each object key that contains "Spend_" to be in separate object.

the initial array looks like:

```js
const data = [
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 1",
    value: {
      Facebook: 17.76,
      Google: 5.36,
      LinkedIn: 14.32,
      Spend_Facebook: 1658317.72,
      Spend_Google: 500179.417,
      Spend_LinkedIn: 1336724.0,
    },
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 2",
    value: {
      Facebook: 13.81,
      Google: 3.22,
      LinkedIn: 12.54,
      Spend_Facebook: 3716170.215,
      Spend_Google: 865968.943,
      Spend_LinkedIn: 3374535.0,
    },
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 3",
    value: {
      Facebook: 15.48,
      Google: 5.84,
      LinkedIn: 30.61,
      Spend_Facebook: 2277128.91,
      Spend_Google: 858674.574,
      Spend_LinkedIn: 4502592.0,
    },
  },
];
```

how to convert it to a formate like this?

```js
const data2 = [
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 1",
    Facebook: 17.76,
    Google: 5.36,
    LinkedIn: 14.32,
    type: 1,
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 1",
    Spend_Facebook: 1658317.72,
    Spend_Google: 500179.417,
    Spend_LinkedIn: 1336724.0,
    type: 2,
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 2",
    Facebook: 13.81,
    Google: 3.22,
    LinkedIn: 12.54,
    type: 1,
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 2",
    Spend_Facebook: 3716170.215,
    Spend_Google: 865968.943,
    Spend_LinkedIn: 3374535.0,
    type: 2,
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 3",
    Facebook: 15.48,
    Google: 5.84,
    LinkedIn: 30.61,
    type: 1,
  },
  {
    flag: 1,
    name: "Brand 3",
    Spend_Facebook: 2277128.91,
    Spend_Google: 858674.574,
    Spend_LinkedIn: 4502592.0,
    type: 2,
  },
];
```

any help to make it work will be appreciated

Comment: I don't know why some people just come and down vote others peoples questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `flatMap` function should do the trick.

```
const data2 = data.flatMap(item => [{
    flag: item.flag,
    name: item.name,
    Facebook: item.value.Facebook,
    Google: item.value.Google,
    LinkedIn: item.value.LinkedIn,
    type: 1
  },{
    flag: item.flag,
    name: item.name,
    Facebook: item.value.Spend_Facebook,
    Google: item.value.Spend_Google,
    LinkedIn: item.value.Spend_LinkedIn,
    type: 2
  }]
);
```

If those keys are dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
const data2 = data.flatMap(item => {
  let type1 = {
    flag: item.flag,
    name: item.name,
    type: 1
  }

  let type2 = {
    flag: item.flag,
    name: item.name,
    type: 2
  }

  for (const key of Object.keys(item.value)){
    if(key.startsWith('Spend_')){
      type2[key.replace('Spend_','')] = item.value[key]
    } else {
      type1[key] = item.value[key]
    }
  }

  return [type1, type2]
});
```

Comment: thank you @Todd Skelton, but the number of items in each object is dynamic which is coming from an api, it can be `{
  flag: 1,
  name: "Brand 2",
  value: {
    Facebook: 13.81,
    Google: 3.22,
    LinkedIn: 12.54,
    Spend_Facebook: 3716170.215,
    Spend_Google: 865968.943,
    Spend_LinkedIn: 3374535.0,
    ...rest
  },`

Comment: Are you saying each object may not be converted into 2? This map function will take your 3 objects and turn it into 6.

Comment: I mean each object may contain more than Google, Facebook, LinkedIn (may contain Instagram, and so on)

Comment: Gotcha, you can loop through the keys in that case.

Comment: yes that is the part that I am looking for answer, maybe the way I asked my question is not correct

Comment: See updated answer for an example of how to do that.